# What file or module actually generates "It worked" in Django tutorials?

Tags: python, django

I have started Django tutorials and got  message "It worked! Congratulations on your first Django-powered page."
I'm trying to make a connection between what I have completed and results,
and I cannot figure out what file or module actually generates this message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default 404 debug view, which handles requests that don't match any configured url, recognizes that you've made no changes to your url configuration. Instead of a technical debug response, it shows you a nice welcome page.

The code can be found in [`django.views.debug`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/debug.py#L476).

Comment: [Line 513](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/debug.py#L513) shows the actual template code :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought it should be somewhere in a Python's django package, but my Windows' search for a string was not successful.